# Find complex integration using Cauchy integration, how to know singularity is inside or outside domain

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

> Find $$\int_C \frac{1}{(z^4-1)}dz$$
>   where $C$ is the circle $|z+i|=\sqrt 3$.

So i tried to break the dominator, $\int_C \frac{1}{(z-1)(z+1)(z+i)(z-i)}dz$
and I knew that the domain is circle with center at $(-i,0)$ and $r=\sqrt 3$
so $z+i$ is point of singularity and $z-i$ is located outside the domain, but how can i know that $z=1$ or $z=-1$ is inside or outside the domain?? though the answer is $z=1$ and $z=-1$ is inside domain.
and how can I made this into $|z-1|=\frac{3}{2}-\sqrt 2$,  $|z+1|=\frac{3}{2}-\sqrt 2$  ? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pole $z_k$ is inside the circle $C$ if and only if its distance from the  center of the circle $-i$ is less then the radius $\sqrt{3}$, i.e.
$$|z_k+i|^2<3.$$
Hence
\begin{align}
&z_1=1\implies |z_1+i|^2=|1+i|^2=1+1=2<3\implies \text{$1$ is inside $C$,}\\
&z_2=-1\implies |z_2+i|^2=|-1+i|^2=1+1=2<3\implies \text{$-1$ is inside $C$,}\\
&z_3=-i\implies |z_3+i|^2=|-i+i|^2=0<3\implies \text{$-i$ is inside $C$,}\\
&z_4=i\implies |z_4+i|^2=|i+i|^2=4>3\implies \text{$i$ is NOT inside $C$.}
\end{align}
Hence, in order to apply the Cauchy Residue Theorem, you have to evaluate the residue at $1$, $-1$, and $-i$.

Comment: thankyou!! and  $ |z-1|=\frac{3}{2}-\sqrt 2$, how can i find the radius? and in this problem with 3 singularity means that i cannot use cauchy integral and have to use cauchy residue?

Comment: The center is $-i$ or $(0,-1)$ not $(-i,0)$. You can use the Cauchy Residue Theorem.

Comment: thanks!! ,but is it necessary to know the radius and center of two small circle (1,0) and (-1,0) -> $|z-1|=\frac{3}{2}-\sqrt 2$, and if i want to use cauchy integra then l i should break it into partial fraction?

Comment: No, it is not necessary to know the radius of the small circle.

Comment: ok thankyou so much for the help!!!^^